# Why would a link in a UIWebView leave a gray box behind?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview that I am loading with custom HTML using loadHtmlString.   My HTML has a   link that I intercept when tapped so that I can take control and reload the UIWebview with a different HTML string.  The code works, but the area where the link text was located is replaced with a gray rectangle that is visible when the new string is loaded.

What could be going on here?  How can I get rid of this behavior?

//Scott

Answer (score 5):

Here it is...need to add this style statement to the link reference:

```
<a href=http://yourlink.com/ style = "-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);">
```

Setting the alpha value (the last parameter to rgba) to 0 disables the tap highlight color.

Although this works, it feels like a hack.  I really think the tap highlight should clear itself when my second loadHtmlString reloads new HTML code.

//Scott

Comment: Dosent work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

You could add `onclick="this.blur(); location.href=this.href;"` to the link to remove the focus from the link.

<sub>I'm sure there's a better less hackish way, but this should work</sub>

Comment: mmm...no go...is there perhaps a webkit-touch parameter that addresses this?