# UIWebView leaves behind link highlight when returning NO from "shouldStartLoadWithRequest"

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

If I return NO in the following method...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

...the grey link highlight around the link that was pressed gets left behind. Is there someway to dismiss the highlight? FYI, I return NO on certain links because I want to do something other than load new content in the web view.

Comment: Sorry for the dup question. Found an answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371036/why-would-a-link-in-a-uiwebview-leave-a-gray-box-behind

Although this solution disables the grey box completely, even during the tap.

Answer (score 1):

I came across your post today. Maybe you've already solved it but I solved it this way:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ffcc99;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could disable it using the following:

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

this can do...